# TouchableOpacity not triggering clicks when nested inside react-native-svg

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

I have a TouchableOpacity nested inside SVG element create by using `react-native-svg` library. It looks something like this:

```html
<Svg
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  top="0%"
  left="0%"
  viewBox="0 0 828 828"
>
  (...)
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
    <Text>Button!</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  (...)
</Svg>
```

Where handleClick is not triggered. I have different implementation for the same feature for Android where TouchableOpacity is outside `Svg` element and `onPress` is correctly triggered. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution? Placing this outside for iOS is not an option,  unfortunately.

Used `react-native-svg` version is 7.0.3

Thanks!